# Disabling roaming profiles on a single server in a network

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, roaming-profile

I want to disable the roaming profiles on a single server which is used as a terminal and RemoteApp server. This option should be applied to all users in the active directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it in the GPO under Administrative Templates > User Profiles. There are two options you have to enable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open GPEDIT.MSC
2. Go to Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\User Profiles
3. Enable both the

   - `Prevent Roaming Profile changes from propagating to the server`
   - `Only allow local user profiles`

This will disable the roaming profiles.